# How to arrange dates in a specific format using sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

![Min Max dates]

![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHEtW.png)
I have a case where i need Find the min of date 1 ,Date 2  and max of date end .

Expected Result is where if Date 1 Date 2 have equal values a  in the consecutive row then min of date 1, min of date 2, max of date end where the constructiveness breaks  .

Please let me know if any clarification is required. .

Code i was using :

```
select  distinct  DAY, county ,
                        case when (Date_2> Date_1 )then (region)  ) then  (region)
                        when (Date_2= Date_1 ) then min (region) Over (Partition By DAY, county )

else region end as region,

                         case when (Date_2> Date_1 ) then  handoff_date
                          when (Date_2= Date_1 ) then  min (handoff_date)  Over (Partition By DAY,county )
                         end as date2,

case when (Date_2= Date_1 )then min(Date_1) Over (Partition By DAY,county ) 

 when (Date_2> Date_1 )then (Date_1)  end as date1


, case when (Date_2= Date_1 )then max(Date_end) Over (Partition By DAY,county ) 


when (Date_2> Date_1 )then (Date_end)    end  as dateEnd 
        from table group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: I would use an OUTER APPLY for this. Then you can just compare the columns.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make the question much easier to follow.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHEtW.png              this is the sample data